# Amazon EC2 How Do I host My Own Content? Stuck on having a working test apache page

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I am using this guide:
http://codingthis.com/platforms/linux/how-to-host-simple-content-with-amazon-elastic-cloud-computing-ec2/

I have a folder named public_html in my /home/ec2-user directory with a test.html file.

What I have done so far:

```
sudo yum -y install httpd php
sudo chkconfig httpd on
chmod 755 /home/ec2-user  (I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT THIS DOES)
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  (changed DocumentRoot to DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/public_html)
```

TLDR: How do I make it load my content (my html file) instead of the apache test page

EXTRA:

I have a security group enabled for my instance with rules:

```
ICMP Allow ALL
TCP Allow ALL
UDP Allow ALL
TCP port 80 (Http)
```

Answer (score 1):

isnt your document root public_html instead of www?  so why did u put ur pages under www directory?

Comment: The chmod command should make your home directory visible to all which i believe is the default behaviour anyways

Comment: You are right, I confused them, I initially had a public_html folder not a www folder

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Dustin I agree it looks deceptively like a comment but it answers the issue at hand so i thought it was justified as an answer.

Comment: The question is "how do I load my content". Your answer doesn't technically answer the question, and it came up for review.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no content in the DocumentRoot that you configured then the default Apache install will show you that page instead of yours.  Also, check the DirectoryIndex configuration to make sure that if you're using index.php or default.html or something else that this is configured as well.  It defaults to index.html

Comment: I have an html file that contains: 
<html>
<body> 
<p>Amazon EC2 server is up and running!</p>                                                                                        ,                                                                   SOLVED!!!                                                            It defaults to index.html not test.html so I renamed my file from test.html to index.html and now it is displaying it.
</body> 
</html>

Comment: +1 Hi @BloodTotal. Did Andrew's answer solve your problem? If so, you should accept his answer because it certainly helped me.

Answer (score 1):

*Chmod755/directory/directory/etc..* Will give access to that directory. So if your website is in the folder *home/ec2-user/public_html* you would then need to give access to that directory.
**Example: chmod 755 home/ec2-user/public_html**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I fixed it by changing the permissions on the ec2-user directory like so:

```
chmod +x home/ec2-user
```

This give execution permissions to everyone on your user directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. All I have to do was just restarting the ec2 to apply the changes. - takes me 2h :(